# How to secure component/path behind authentication in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hello I am trying to make a certain path "/main" only accessible to logged in users. I have a loginUser action that sends the login request then redirects to "/main". However if you just type in "/main" after localhost:3000 without loggin in you can still get to "/main". Any help appreciated.

Here is my action:

```
export function loginUser(username1, password1) {
const mainPage = (response, dispatch) => {
  if(true) {
    history.push('/main');
  }
  dispatch({
      type: POST_DATA_SUCCESS,
      response,
  });
 };
const promise = fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/login', {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username1 + ":" + password1),
 },
 body: JSON.stringify({
   username: username1,
   password: password1,
  })
 });
 return {
    onRequest: POST_DATA_TRIGGERED,
    onSuccess: mainPage,
    onFailure: POST_DATA_FAILURE,
    promise,
  };
  }
```

Here is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from '../history'
import Journal from './journal';
import AddForm from './add-form';
import GetSearch from './old-search';
import SignUp from './signup';
import Front from './front';
import { loginUser } from '../actions';

export default function App(props) {
  return(
   <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <h3><Link className="title-journey" to="/">A Journey of Life</Link>
      </h3>
       <main>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Journal} />
        <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
        <Route path="/add" component={AddForm} />
        <Route path="/get" component={GetSearch} />
        <Route path="/main" component={Front} />
       </main>
    </div>
   </Router>
  );
 }
```

And here is my login.js component:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
 import { loginUser } from '../actions';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 export class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   //username: '',
   //password: '',
   }
 }

login(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 const userName = this.username.value;
 const passWord = this.password.value;
 console.log(userName);
 console.log(passWord);
  this.props.loginUser(userName, passWord);
 }

render() {
  return(
    <form>
     <h3>Login to start your Journey</h3>
     <input placeholder="username" ref={input => {this.username = input}}>
     </input>
     <input placeholder="password" type="password"ref={input => 
     {this.password = input}}></input>
     <button onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Login</button>
    </form>
   )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { loginUser })(Login);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using react-router v4.  They recommend using the render prop on the Route component to render a redirect when the user does not have proper authorization.  It is a component that looks like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
```

And then your app would look like

```
   <main>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Journal} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
    <Route path="/add" component={AddForm} />
    <Route path="/get" component={GetSearch} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/main" component={Front} />
   </main>
```

How you check to see if the user is authenticated is up to you, i.e `fakeAuth.isAuthenticated`